# What does meta+n do in the terminal

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

When I click this it replaces whatever I have currently typed into the buffer with a `:`.

Hitting backspace will go back to whatever I had in the buffer but I can't seem to find what the hell it's supposed to do. It reminds me of a prompt for typing commands into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's prompting for a string to search for in your input history.
From the [bash readline documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Searching)

> `non-incremental-forward-search-history (M-n)`
>
> Search forward starting at the current line and moving ‘down’ through the the history as necessary using a non-incremental search for a string supplied by the user.

So if you've cycled back through your input history with up-arrow, you can use this to search forward to a line that matches a string.

There's a similar <kbd>M-p</kbd> command that searches backwards.